# embed and resize a swf video

Tags: html, flash, embed

I am trying to figure out the best way to embed and resize swf videos.

Here is the url to one of the videos I am looking to embed.
http://help.servdot.com/cpanel-whm/cpanel/x3/m/Logging-into-cPanel.php

The example embed code is

```
<iframe src="http://help.servdot.com/cpanel-whm/cpanel/x3/m/Logging-into-cPanel.swf" width="780" height="624" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

When I change the dimensions it crops the video and I need it to scale, Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an "answer" but, just to share what I think: I believe this (resizing) depends on the underlying flash (swf) file being able to handle scaling or not. In this particular case, it seems that "Logging-into-cPanel.swf" does not handle it, and does not pay attention to the size of the canvas it resides, and always centers itself (i.e. cropping when the container is smaller)

I haven't done network sniffing, or flash decompiling to see if this SWF file is just a wrapper around a FLV file or something. If that's the case, you may be able to switch to a different player, and handle it, but otherwise, there may not be a way (but then again, I'm not a Flash expert).

Answer (score 0):

try using the "object" tag instead of the "iframe" tag ... I think the following might be a bit of a help,

http://animation.about.com/od/flashanimationtutorials/qt/embedswfwebpage.htm